# Revised manuscript for a long time

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, review-articles, elsevier

We have submitted a review to high-impact factor journal in Elsevier, and after 15 days only, the reviewing process has ended with major revision. We addressed the suggested point carefully and the revised manuscript has been re-submitted. The status has returned back to under review and for 1 month no update on the status.
Is it common for the revised manuscript to take longer time than the original one?